# How to disable automatic adjustment of brightness/contrast when creating a stack of images

Tags: image-processing, imagej

I have a large number of images that form time series, but they vary in brightness and contrast significantly. It's very easy to adjust the brightness/contrast on a per image basis, however, when I create an ImageStack with a few of them, the whole brightness/contrast gets auto adjusted, based on the top image.

So, is there a way to disable this automatic adjustment?

Comment: Are you doing this programatically or just using the GUI? Do you write Java code creating a imageStack and ImagePlus?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it programmatically, and I'm actually using JRuby as the scripting language. However, I don't think I fully understood the way ImageJ shows images - when brightness/contrast are changed (i.e. `min` and `max`), they are only changed for the displayed image, yet LUT is untouched. So, in order to actually apply the settings programmatically (in GUI it's Brightness/Contrast Apply button), one has to use `LutApplier`'s `run` on per-image basis, before creating a stack from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distinction is between thresholding and applying a LUT although either could produce the same effect. The [ImageProcessor](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html) class contains methods to set both the [LUT](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#setLut%28ij.process.LUT%29) and [thresholding](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#setThreshold%28double,%20double,%20int%29). You should be able to turn off the auto thresholding from this class too.

Since a separate ImageProcessor is associated with each slice in your stack you can apply any LUT or thresholding (provided they aren't colour) to each slice.